# I can't share internet in Ubuntu 13.04 with a windows device like I could in 12.10

Tags: 13.04, internet, connection-sharing

I have IPv4 set to share internet, but with my Windows machine it will work for a few minutes and then just stop working. Can anyone tell me if there's a new way to do this, or if it is broken in this build at the moment?

*****fix
Well, I found a fix that worked for me. The problem for me was in the new linux kernal 3.8. So i rebooted my pc and held shift to go to grub manager. From there I selected ubuntu advanced options and selected kernal 3.5 and it works fine for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing right now with Wireless and Wired device. Both are working, so most probably it is a bug right now. It would be good if you could include the wired device you are using. You could try searching for the option [Launchpad's Bug Search](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu?field.searchtext=&search=Search&field.status%3alist=NEW&field.status%3alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=).

What I did notice in another computer is that the wired connection was not working because I updated from 12.10. After doing a fresh install with 13.04 it worked perfectly. This last info might help if you did an upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04. I would also recommend checking the output of `dmesg` out to see if it says something related to the problem.